# Looking for a button or shortcut for accessing Google Chrome's Create Application Shortcut feature - any ideas?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, google-chrome, chromium, shortcuts

In Google Chrome, their extremely useful Create Application Shortcuts is buried under Wrench icon > Tools > Create Application Shortcuts.  I'd really like a Chrome button, bookmarklet or a even desktop or Unity launcher to make accessing this menu a one-click process.

Even if someone knew the command flag for opening the Create Application Shortcuts prompt that would be a great help.  Thanks!

Comment: And you've tried the command line with **--help**?  If there is a command, it would be simple to create a launcher icon.

Comment: I have, along with the complete list of command flags but no dice.  Even willing to use a Firefox solution but not finding anything relevant there either..

Comment: What exact version?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 x64, and Chrome 15.0.874.121.

Though creating a launcher icon is easy enough, I'm simply looking for a one-click way to pull up the Create Application Shortcuts menu (for newbs that won't know to look for it in the wrench > tools menu)

Answer (score 1):

(my best guess)

from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1275363

You are looking for a "**one click**" method of converting the current URL (from Chrome or Firefox) to the desktop, where this can be used as a **'desktop shortcut'**.

And, you want this 'icon' to load the URL (website) as a browser window **without toolbars, statusbars, and the like**.

***Please confirm, and/or clarify ..***

Comment: (Sorry for the very delayed reply; I didn't realize there was a reply and adjusted my notification settings)

One click method:  YES

Load with toolbars, etc:  Preferable but not critical


Thanks!!